# ReadLine não pede a digitação do dado

Tags: c#, .net, entrada-de-dados

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("1-Encriptar");
        Console.WriteLine("2-Decriptar");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        int escolha = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        Boolean b;
        algoritmo("", "", true);
    }
    private static void algoritmo(String input, String chave, Boolean b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a mensagem: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a chave: ");
        chave = Console.ReadLine();
        input = input.ToUpper();
        chave = chave.ToUpper();
```

Quando eu mando executar, o console pede o número da opção e eu digito 1, logo em seguida as duas mensagens "digite mensagem, digite chave" aparecem sem que eu escreva mensagem pra *input* e vai direto pra chave. O que eu faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código tem vários erros técnicos e conceituais e foge do idioma regular moderno do C#.

Prefira usar os nomes dos tipos que a linguagem usa, prefira, `int`, `string`, `bool`.

Pode importar a classe estática e simplificar o código.

Se digitasse uma letra no menu a aplicação quebraria. Você tem que verificar se o usuário digitou algo válido. Eu nem vou verificar se digitou algo diferente de 1 e 2, deixo isso para você.

Esse método tem parâmetros que não serve para nada, tirei. tinha variáveis sem uso.

Evite converter para maiúsculo. a não ser que queira imprimir em maiúsculo mesmo. Se for só facilitar a comparação e não lidar com caixa baixa e alta misturada, tem técnicas melhores.

O problema principal é que você usou um `Read()`que não faz o que você imagina, tem que usar o `ReadLine()` mesmo. O `Read()` só vai pegar uma tecla pressionada e devolver um código da tecla, não retornará o que você digitou. Nem ficará esperando a digitação. Quando você digita 1 na verdade está digitando a mensagem.

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
 public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO");
        WriteLine("-----------------");
        WriteLine("1-Encriptar");
        WriteLine("2-Decriptar");
        WriteLine("-----------------");
        int escolha;
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out escolha)) {
            WriteLine("Opção inválida");
            return; //dá pra fazer melhor que isso, mas agora vai simples mesmo
        }
        algoritmo();
    }
    private static void algoritmo() {
        WriteLine("Digite a mensagem: ");
        var input = ReadLine();
        WriteLine("Digite a chave: ");
        var chave = ReadLine();
        //input = input.ToUpper(); //não faça isto se não precisa mesmo, em geral não precisa
        //chave = chave.ToUpper(); //tem tecnicas melhores para facilitar para o usuário não se preocupar com caixa
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wKs8id). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/32VyDf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/ReadReadLine.cs).

Comment: Muito obrigado. O objetivo de usar .ToUpper() era restringir aos valores do intervalo [65;90] da tabela ascii, pra tentar encriptar usando a cifra de vigenere.

Comment: @YanPodkorytoff agora você pode votar em todo site também.